# Чем обусловлено ограничениеие поддержки карт памяти по размеру?

Tags: память, sd

На разных устройствах пишут ограничение размера используемой карты sd. 
Я понимаю, что производитель не гарантирует работу устройства с картой памяти больше заявленного размера, однако, с точки зрения техники, на большей карте всего лишь больше объём, но та же фс, та же таблица разделов. Некоторые производители заявляют поддержку до 2тб, при том, что таких карт пока (вроде бы, слышал только про 1тб) не существует в природе.

Вопрос в том, чем обусловлено ограничение и чем чревато в общем случае нарушение? Разумеется, сугубо теоретически.

Comment: Скорее всего ограничение связано с разрядностью адреса в драйвере карты. Чтобы не считать лишние байты ограничивают разрядность адреса, но с некоторым запасом. Через пару лет появятся карты 4 Тб и в драйвере добавят разрядов адреса.

Comment: @pepsicoca Спасибо, это может быть правдой, но я наткнулся на интересное ограничение (откуда, собственно, и родился вопрос), в 400гб. Учитывая, что в ит кратность адреса, как правило, составляет два в некоторой степени, я делаю допущение, что не будет проблемой, если я вставлю карту памяти 512гб в это устройство, едва ли разрядность будет отличаться от карт на 256гб, которые попадают в диапазон. Как думаете, это заблуждение?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 наверное, не заблуждение, потому что sd, как и sdhc, как и sdxc это стандарты, при этом стандарт sdxc, как я понял, описывает семейство карт от 32ГБ до 2ТБ, и так, как это стандарт, и размер кластера фиксированный, можно предположить, что и размер адреса будет фиксированный. По крайней мере такие мысли наводит на меня вот эта статья https://m.habr.com/ru/post/213803/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я наткнулся на интересное ограничение (откуда, собственно, и родился
>   вопрос), в 400гб

Откуда может быть размер самой карты в 400 Гб (то есть не кратно двойки) вобщем-то понятно. Какой массив памяти поместился на кристалле, такие карты производитель и выпускает. Конечно, адресный регистр там позволяет адресовать ближайшую к заявленной и кратную степени двойки емкость накопителя. Но если технологически на данном кристалле и при данном техпроцессе умещается только 400 Гб, то старшие разряды адреса будут висеть в воздухе и не использоваться.

Если же заявлена поддержка по чтению карт в 400 Гб, то это менее понятно. Может быть это скрытая маркетинговая попытка стимулировать покупать новые устройства. Во всяком случае технически адрес (и адресный регистр) в теперешних наших реалиях всегда кратен степени двойки.

Comment: Я в итоге не стал рисковать, и заказал себе по объему, потому что поддержка продукта в данном случае скромно сказала "мы не знаем" без каких либо обоснований ответа, кроме "мы не проверяли". Вам в любом случае спасибо за ответ, прояснили для меня ситуацию